# Is it possible to compare with a number in "Where"?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-4

I am new in **Entity Framework** and I have a little question.
Is it possible to compare in "Where" with a number.
I will add code example.

```
var source = db.Book.Where(book => book.Count > 0);
```

So, I need to get all book items where count more than zero.
Thanks in advance for your help!
[Here is the structure of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9tiU.png)

Comment: The count of what exactly? Are you storing the same book more than once? (I which case the data is probably not normalized.) Do you mean the number in stock? The number per reseller or something completely different? Please, show us your table schema or class structure.

Comment: *Is it possible* -- We can't possibly tell seeing only this isolated line of code. You should be able to tell though if you just run the code.

Comment: I have added a picture of database diagram. I hope it's clearer now

Comment: A class model is usually better, in text, not an image. There doesn't seem to be a book.Count property, which means you probably posted pseudo code. That's hardly ever helpful because it's not clear what it actually does or should do. You better explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: `Books` is a "table", thus, an entry of `Book` does not have "Count". If you want to see Authors/Publishers/Genres with more than 0 books, your query should be directed towards their corresponding dbsets. An example about Genres with more than 0 books could be `db.Genres.Where(genre => genre.Books.Count > 0);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are trying to query the entire table to check if there is any record, yet you can do something like:

```
var query = context.Books.Any() ? context.Books.ToList() : null;

if (query is not null)
{
    query.ForEach(b =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ID:{b.Id}, Title:{b.Title}");
    });
}
```

However, if you are trying to find out if there is duplication available, you can use the following query:

```
var query = context.Books.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Title == "some title") 
    is not null ? context.Books.ToList() : null;

if (query is not null)
{
    query.ForEach(b =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ID:{b.Id}, Title:{b.Title}");
    });
}
```

By the way, I don't think it is a good idea to have such a scenario.